# SSAS TAbular Role hide some of tables

Tags: sql, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have some tables in my SSAS Tabular, but I want to hide some table for certain user. 
Ex : I have Sales, Bonus, and master tables.
For Operation Department user cannot see bonus's table.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Read` [role](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213165.aspx#bkmk_permissions) for those users/groups.
Use the row filter `=FALSE()` on any column of the tables you want to hide.
No rows on those tables will be available to those users.

If you don't want them to see the dimension at all create a [perspective](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230816.aspx) that doesn't include the tables (in addition to the create role).